# dotted stroke in <canvas>

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I guess it is not possible to set stroke property such as CSS which is quite easy. With CSS we have dashed, dotted, solid but on canvas when drawing lines/or strokes this doesn't seem to be an option. How have you implemented this?

I've seen some examples but they are really long for such a silly function.

For example:

http://groups.google.com/group/javascript-information-visualization-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/22000c0d0a1c54f9?pli=1

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Fun question! I've written a custom implementation of dashed lines; you can [try it out here](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_dashed_line.html). I took the route of Adobe Illustrator and allow you to specify an array of dash/gap lengths.

For stackoverflow posterity, here's my implementation (slightly altered for s/o line widths):

```
var CP = window.CanvasRenderingContext2D && CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype;
if (CP && CP.lineTo){
  CP.dashedLine = function(x,y,x2,y2,dashArray){
    if (!dashArray) dashArray=[10,5];
    if (dashLength==0) dashLength = 0.001; // Hack for Safari
    var dashCount = dashArray.length;
    this.moveTo(x, y);
    var dx = (x2-x), dy = (y2-y);
    var slope = dx ? dy/dx : 1e15;
    var distRemaining = Math.sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy );
    var dashIndex=0, draw=true;
    while (distRemaining>=0.1){
      var dashLength = dashArray[dashIndex++%dashCount];
      if (dashLength > distRemaining) dashLength = distRemaining;
      var xStep = Math.sqrt( dashLength*dashLength / (1 + slope*slope) );
      if (dx<0) xStep = -xStep;
      x += xStep
      y += slope*xStep;
      this[draw ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](x,y);
      distRemaining -= dashLength;
      draw = !draw;
    }
  }
}
```

To draw a line from `20,150` to `170,10` with dashes that are 30px long followed by a gap of 10px, you would use:

```
myContext.dashedLine(20,150,170,10,[30,10]);
```

To draw alternating dashes and dots, use (for example):

```
myContext.lineCap   = 'round';
myContext.lineWidth = 4; // Lines 4px wide, dots of diameter 4
myContext.dashedLine(20,150,170,10,[30,10,0,10]);
```

The "very short" dash length of `0` combined with the rounded lineCap results in dots along your line.

*If anyone knows of a way to access the current point of a canvas context path, I'd love to know about it, as it would allow me to write this as `ctx.dashTo(x,y,dashes)` instead of requiring you to re-specify the start point in the method call.*

Comment: @Sam You're not the only one who thinks that we should not have been made to do this much work to draw dotted lines on Canvas: http://lists.whatwg.org/pipermail/whatwg-whatwg.org/2007-May/011224.html

Comment: This seems to be the best implementation that I have found.  I am curious, however, what the first line accomplishes.  I would expect the && operator to return a boolean result which is then being assigned to CP.  I am a relative novice to JavaScript so I wonder whether I am missing something fundamental.

Comment: @Jon JavaScript's _"boolean operators"_ are actually _"guard operators"_. Using short-circuit evaluation they return whichever value's 'truthiness' is evaluated last. Here are some true statements: `42 == 42 || "hi"; "hi" == false || "hi"; true == 17 && true; false == 17 && false; "" == "" && false`. Open up your friendly developer console and experiment for yourself. :) The first line sets `CP` to the prototype if `CanvasRenderingContext2D` exists, otherwise it sets it to `undefined`.

Comment: Made a public gist on github hope you don't mind https://gist.github.com/4137120 thanks for the great code

Comment: When the difference in x coordinates is 0, you're dividing by zero and it doesn't work.

Comment: Awesome. You have some of my favourite answers on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HonzaBrabec Yes, you're right. That's fixed with the `1e15` hack. There are other cleaner ways to do it, but this requires the least code changes and is sufficiently effective.

Answer (score 43):

This simplified version of Phrogz's code utilises the built-in transformation functionality of Canvas and also handles special cases e.g. when dx = 0

```
var CP = window.CanvasRenderingContext2D && CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype;
if (CP.lineTo) {
    CP.dashedLine = function(x, y, x2, y2, da) {
        if (!da) da = [10,5];
        this.save();
        var dx = (x2-x), dy = (y2-y);
        var len = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
        var rot = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        this.translate(x, y);
        this.moveTo(0, 0);
        this.rotate(rot);       
        var dc = da.length;
        var di = 0, draw = true;
        x = 0;
        while (len > x) {
            x += da[di++ % dc];
            if (x > len) x = len;
            draw ? this.lineTo(x, 0): this.moveTo(x, 0);
            draw = !draw;
        }       
        this.restore();
    }
}
```

*I think my calculations are correct and it seems to render OK.*

Comment: Just wanted to mention that Phrogz's solution isn't working for vertical lines. This solution works.

Comment: Might be good to guard against a dashedLine function already being defined: `CP.dashedLine = CP.dashedLine || function...`

Comment: Also, `CP` can be undefined (if `!window.CanvasRenderingContext2D`) in which case the `CP.lineTo` bit would fail.

Answer (score 10):

At the moment at least setLineDash([5,10]) works with Chrome and ctx.mozDash = [5,10] works with FF:

```
var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

if ( ctx.setLineDash !== undefined )   ctx.setLineDash([5,10]);
if ( ctx.mozDash !== undefined )       ctx.mozDash = [5,10];

ctx.beginPath();              
ctx.lineWidth="2";
ctx.strokeStyle="green";
ctx.moveTo(0,75);
ctx.lineTo(250,75);
ctx.stroke();
```

Setting to null makes the line solid.

Comment: IE 11 seems to support setLineDash too:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265063(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As of Dec '15 all current browsers support setLineDash according to **DMN**: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setLineDash#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 7):

Phroz's solution is great. But when I used it in my application, I found two bugs.

Following code is debugged (and refactored for readability) version of Phroz's one.

```js
// Fixed: Minus xStep bug (when x2 < x, original code bugs)
// Fixed: Vertical line bug (when abs(x - x2) is zero, original code bugs because of NaN)
var CP = window.CanvasRenderingContext2D && CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype;
if(CP && CP.lineTo) CP.dashedLine = function(x, y, x2, y2, dashArray){
    if(! dashArray) dashArray=[10,5];
    var dashCount = dashArray.length;
    var dx = (x2 - x);
    var dy = (y2 - y);
    var xSlope = (Math.abs(dx) > Math.abs(dy));
    var slope = (xSlope) ? dy / dx : dx / dy;

    this.moveTo(x, y);
    var distRemaining = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    var dashIndex = 0;
    while(distRemaining >= 0.1){
        var dashLength = Math.min(distRemaining, dashArray[dashIndex % dashCount]);
        var step = Math.sqrt(dashLength * dashLength / (1 + slope * slope));
        if(xSlope){
            if(dx < 0) step = -step;
            x += step
            y += slope * step;
        }else{
            if(dy < 0) step = -step;
            x += slope * step;
            y += step;
        }
        this[(dashIndex % 2 == 0) ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](x, y);
        distRemaining -= dashLength;
        dashIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Mozilla has been working on an [implementation of dashed stroking](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=662038) for canvas, so we may see it added to the spec in the near future.

Comment: VERIFIED FIXED a few months ago.

Answer (score 5):

There's a much simpler way to do this. According to http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-strokestyle strokeStyle accepts strings, CanvasGradients, or CanvasPatterns. So we just take an image like this:

```
  <img src="images/dashedLineProto.jpg" id="cvpattern1" width="32" height="32" />
```

[image]

load it into a canvas, and draw our little rectangle with it.

```
  var img=document.getElementById("cvpattern1");
  var pat=ctx.createPattern(img,"repeat");
  ctx.strokeStyle = pat;
  ctx.strokeRect(20,20,150,100);
```

that doesnt result in a perfect dashed line, but it's really straightforward and modifiable. Results may of course become imperfect when you're drawing lines which arent horizontal or vertical, a dotted pattern might help there.

PS. keep in mind SOP applies when you're trying to use imgs from external sources in your code.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like context.setLineDash is pretty much implemented.
See [this](http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/january/html5-canvas-dashed-lines.html).

" context.setLineDash([5])
 will result in a dashed line where both the dashes and spaces are 5 pixels in size. "

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no support in HTML5 Canvas specification for dashed lines.

check this out:

http://davidowens.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/html-5-canvas-and-dashed-lines/

or

Check out the Raphael JS Library:

http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 2):

There are support for it in [Firefox at least](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/CanvasRenderingContext2D#Gecko-specific_attributes)

```
ctx.mozDash = [5,10];
```

seems like `ctx.webkitLineDash` worked before, but they removed it because it had some [compabillity issues](http://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=80674).

The [W3C specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#line-styles) says `ctx.setLineDash([5,10]);` but it doesn't seem to be implemented yet anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I made modified the `dashedLine` function to add support for offsetting. It utilizes native dashed lines if the browser supports `ctx.setLineDash` and `ctx.lineDashOffset`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mLY8Q/6/

```
var CP = window.CanvasRenderingContext2D && CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype;
if (CP.lineTo) {

    CP.dashedLine = CP.dashedLine || function (x, y, x2, y2, da, offset) {

        if (!da) da = [10, 5];
        if (!offset) offset = 0;

        if (CP.setLineDash && typeof (CP.lineDashOffset) == "number") {
            this.save();
            this.setLineDash(da);
            this.lineDashOffset = offset;

            this.moveTo(x, y);
            this.lineTo(x2, y2);

            this.restore();
            return;
        }


        this.save();
        var dx = (x2 - x),
            dy = (y2 - y);
        var len = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        var rot = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        this.translate(x, y);
        this.moveTo(0, 0);
        this.rotate(rot);
        var dc = da.length;
        var di = 0;

        var patternLength = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < dc; i++) {
            patternLength += da[i];
        }
        if (dc % 2 == 1) {
            patternLength *= 2;
        }

        offset = offset % patternLength;
        if (offset < 0) {
            offset += patternLength;
        }

        var startPos = 0;
        var startSegment = 0;
        while (offset >= startPos) {



            if (offset >= startPos + da[startSegment % dc]) {
                startPos += da[startSegment % dc];
                startSegment++;
            } else {
                offset = Math.abs(offset - startPos);
                break;
            }


            if (startSegment > 100) break;
        }
        draw = startSegment % 2 === 0;
        x = 0;
        di = startSegment;


        while (len > x) {
            var interval = da[di++ % dc];
            if (x < offset) {
                interval = Math.max(interval - offset, 1);
                offset = 0;
            }

            x += interval;
            if (x > len) x = len;
            draw ? this.lineTo(x, 0) : this.moveTo(x, 0);
            draw = !draw;
        }
        this.restore();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found properties `mozDash` and `mozDashOffset` in Mozilla specification: 
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/interfaces/canvas/nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.idl

They're probaly used to control dashes, but i haven't used them.