# Find current point on path for HTML Canvas context?

Tags: html, canvas

If I have an HTML Canvas context and do:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10,10);
ctx.lineTo(20,30);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();
```

...a line is drawn between 10,10 and 20,30. Suppose I have this:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10,10);
myFunction(ctx);
```

Is there any way for `myFunction()` to find out that the path 'cursor' is currently at `10,10`?

Comment: Why would you need myFunction() to know the current location of 'cursor'? Note that the context works like a state machine. If you call "ctx.lineTo(20,30)" etc. at myFunction it should work.

Comment: @bebraw Because I want to write [`ctx.dashTo(x,y,...)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576724/dotted-stroke-in-canvas/4577326#4577326); for that, I need to know where I am in addition to where I am going in order to calculate various points along the way.

Comment: Righto. I think in that case you may be better off by implementing a wrapper for Context. Retain the data you need there and extend the API as you like. If you want I can provide you a simple example to get started better. :)

Comment: Just found this, https://github.com/millermedeiros/CanvasContext2DWrapper . Another one, http://code.google.com/p/canto-js/ .

Comment: @bebraw Thank you for the offer; I can wrap or intercept methods on the context effectively by myself if need be. However, if you know for certain that the data I seek can not be accessed on the context API, post that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there's no direct way to access arguments passed to various ctx methods (ie. moveTo in this case). You can wrap the Context API into a class of its own to do this, however. See [[1](https://github.com/millermedeiros/CanvasContext2DWrapper)] and 
[[2](http://code.google.com/p/canto-js/)] for reference.