# Getting a canvas-context's last point's coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to create an `arrowTo` function with `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype`. To do that, I need to get the coordinates of the last point, e.g.

```
//... 
var ctx = someCanvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.moveTo(10,40);
//the coordinates of the last point are now (10,40)

ctx.lineTo(50,50);
//and now it's (50,50)

//...
```

How can I retrieve them?

Comment: Just store them in a variable whenever you draw?

Comment: Duplicate of [Find current point on path for HTML Canvas context?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577410/find-current-point-on-path-for-html-canvas-context); I wish this were possible, but it's not without wrapping the canvas context in a wrapper that tracks this.

Comment: see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=644633

Comment: [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) could be interesting, also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28913470).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'd have to keep track of them yourself. Or do the unthinkable and override moveTo/lineTo to keep track of the last coords via `CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype`.

Answer (score 9):

This is a property that canvas HAS STORED somewhere and it should be available from a property (likely) because it can be difficult tracking last point coordinates.
For example when you draw an arc

```
ctx.arc(xc, yc, radius, starting_angle, ending_angle);
```

You don't have immediate information of the last point coordinates.
Of course this can be obtained in this case with

```
lastX = xc + radius*Math.cos(ending_angle);
lastY = yc + radius*Math.sin(ending_angle);
```

But it is irritating needing to include those computations when we know that canvas does remember last point.
If after the arc instruction you add a

```
ctx.lineTo(x, y);
```

And it does work. Therefore canvas has that last point stored somewhere and I can't understand  why it is hidden for the programmer.

Comment: This don't answer the question. On the contrary, this just describe the problem... **`:(`**