# toDataURL() small screens, small saved image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have created a web application which uses an HTML5 canvas element to allow users to draw in various shapes, colors, line widths. They can also upload an image, have it drawn onto the canvas and then draw on top of that, as a way to annotate their images.

My challenge is that I am using .toDataURL() to get the entire contents of the canvas saved as an image. As I understand, though, this can only capture the size of the canvas. On smaller devices (phones), the image which is saved, ends up quite small dimensions. Here's what I am doing to get what is on the canvas:

var image = document.getElementById("drawingCanvas").toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);

image = image.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '').replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');

Is there some way to set up my canvas to be able to save larger images, even if the size of the canvas is quite small, due to the device?

Answer (score 0):

**Sure...**

1. Save the commands used to create the client's drawing.
2. Create a larger in-memory canvas with `document.createElement`.
3. `drawImage` a full-sized image to the canvas.
4. `context.scale` the canvas.
5. Re-issue the drawing commands.
6. Export the enlarged canvas with `.toDataURL`.

Thanks to `context.scale` you don't have to change any of the coordinates of the drawing commands.

**...and alternatively...**

You could eliminate step#1 if you're willing to downgrade the drawings to allow some "jaggies". Do this by using CSS to overlay a canvas on top of the client's img. That way the client's drawings are already isolated on the original canvas. Then your procedure simplifies to:

1. Create a larger in-memory canvas with `document.createElement`. Make sure the larger canvas has the same aspect ratio as the original canvas.
2. `drawImage` a full-sized image to the canvas.
3. `drawImage` the original smaller canvas to the larger canvas. You can use the extended version of drawImage to simultaneously scale the client's drawings: `context.drawImage(originalCanvas, 0, 0, originalCanvas.width, originalCanvas.height, 0, 0, largerCanvas.width, largerCanvas.height)`. Yes, the image source for `drawImage` can be another canvas. ;-)
4. Export the enlarged canvas with `.toDataURL`.

Comment: The first solution sounds promising, but I don't know how to save the commands. I will need to though, for another reason as well. I will be adding an "undo" button in the future. How do you save commands?

Comment: [Here's a previous SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19471369/html5-canvas-manipulating-individual-paths/19471856#19471856) that shows how to serialize a path into a javascript object and then redraw the path.

Comment: Ok, super. I really appreciate it. I will give this all a try and report back.