# Get x/y position of triangle from canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to draw a triangle and store it's x/y coordindates. Following
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes

```
function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (canvas.getContext){
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.translate(0,100);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(75,50);
    // READ X/Y VALUE HERE
    ctx.lineTo(100,75);
    // READ X/Y VALUE HERE
    ctx.lineTo(100,25);
    // READ X/Y VALUE HERE
    ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

How do I get the x/y values in the places marked, as the translate will mean the values put into **moveTo** and **lineTo** will be different.

Thanks

Comment: Store them in a data structure.

Comment: If you know, where you draw the triangle exactly, then what's your problem?

Comment: The moveTo/lineTo are relative to the translate performed earlier. I want to be able to get the absolute position of these without having to keep track of all the translates

Comment: looks like you're looking for something very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577410/find-current-point-on-path-for-html-canvas-context)