# HTML5 Animating a dashed line

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, path

Being relatively new to the HTML5 game, just wanted to ask if anyone knew if it was possible to animate a dashed line along a path? Think snake from Nokia days, just with a dashed line...

I've got a dashed line (which represents electrical current flow), which I'd like to animate as 'moving' to show that current is flowing to something.

Thanks to Rod's answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576724/dotted-stroke-in-canvas) post, I've got the dashed line going, but am not sure where to start to get it moving. Anyone know where to begin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Got it working <s>[here](http://jsfiddle.net/8dVTE/)</s>, based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576724/dotted-stroke-in-canvas) by [phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz).

What i did:

- Add a `start` parameter which is a number between 0 and 99
- Calculate the `dashSize` summing the contents of the dash array
- Calculate `dashOffSet` as a fraction of `dashSize` based on `start` percent
- Subtracted the offset from x, y and added to dx, dy
- Only started drawying after the offset been gone (it´s negative, remember)
- Added a `setInterval` to update the `start` from 0 to 99, step of 10

---

**Update**

The original algorithm wasn't working for vertical or negative inclined lines. Added a check to use the inclination based on the y slope on those cases, and not on the x slope.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/H7rPH/)

Updated code:

```
if (window.CanvasRenderingContext2D && CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.lineTo) {
    CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.dashedLine = function(x, y, x2, y2, dashArray, start) {
        if (!dashArray) dashArray = [10, 5];
        var dashCount = dashArray.length;
        var dashSize = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < dashCount; i++) dashSize += parseInt(dashArray[i]);
        var dx = (x2 - x),
            dy = (y2 - y);
        var slopex = (dy < dx);
        var slope = (slopex) ? dy / dx : dx / dy;
        var dashOffSet = dashSize * (1 - (start / 100))
        if (slopex) {
            var xOffsetStep = Math.sqrt(dashOffSet * dashOffSet / (1 + slope * slope));
            x -= xOffsetStep;
            dx += xOffsetStep;
            y -= slope * xOffsetStep;
            dy += slope * xOffsetStep;
        } else {
            var yOffsetStep = Math.sqrt(dashOffSet * dashOffSet / (1 + slope * slope));
            y -= yOffsetStep;
            dy += yOffsetStep;
            x -= slope * yOffsetStep;
            dx += slope * yOffsetStep;
        }
        this.moveTo(x, y);
        var distRemaining = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        var dashIndex = 0,
            draw = true;
        while (distRemaining >= 0.1 && dashIndex < 10000) {
            var dashLength = dashArray[dashIndex++ % dashCount];
            if (dashLength > distRemaining) dashLength = distRemaining;
            if (slopex) {
                var xStep = Math.sqrt(dashLength * dashLength / (1 + slope * slope));
                x += xStep
                y += slope * xStep;
            } else {
                var yStep = Math.sqrt(dashLength * dashLength / (1 + slope * slope));
                y += yStep
                x += slope * yStep;
            }
            if (dashOffSet > 0) {
                dashOffSet -= dashLength;
                this.moveTo(x, y);
            } else {
                this[draw ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](x, y);
            }
            distRemaining -= dashLength;
            draw = !draw;
        }
        // Ensure that the last segment is closed for proper stroking
        this.moveTo(0, 0);
    }
}

var dashes = '10 20 2 20'

var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
c.width = 300;
c.height = 400;
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';

var drawDashes = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    var dashGapArray = dashes.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(/\s+/);
    if (!dashGapArray[0] || (dashGapArray.length == 1 && dashGapArray[0] == 0)) return;

    ctx.lineWidth = 4;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.dashedLine(10, 0, 10, c.height, dashGapArray, currentOffset);
    ctx.dashedLine(0, 10, c.width, 10, dashGapArray, currentOffset);
    ctx.dashedLine(0, 0, c.width, c.height, dashGapArray, currentOffset);
    ctx.dashedLine(0, c.height, c.width, 0, dashGapArray, currentOffset);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
};
window.setInterval(dashInterval, 500);

var currentOffset = 0;

function dashInterval() {
    drawDashes();
    currentOffset += 10;
    if (currentOffset >= 100) currentOffset = 0;
}
```

Comment: @ariel, That's exactly what I was after! I've been playing with it all day, and couldn't get the offsets to work properly. Thanks so much! Oh, and I'm loving JSFiddle, I'd never seen/heard of something like that! Great for hacking something together as above...

Comment: Oh, and your solution doesn't seem to work for downward lines (straight on y axis), but works perfectly fine for diagonal or horizontal lines (straight on x axis). Any ideas?

Comment: In that case the slope is infinite.. I guess the original algo wouldnt work as well. You have to check if dy > dx use the slope based on y.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that's what was happening..I'll really only be using it for 90° lines. So something like var slope = (dy > dx) ? dy/dx : y; ?

Comment: Thanks @ariel, that's awesome! My solution was missing the second check for slopex, your solution it much more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the dashed line animation using SNAPSVG library.

Please check the tutorial here [DEMO](https://blog.knesk.com/svg-dotted-graph-animation-using-snap-svg-library/)
[image: Dashed Animation]