# drawing lines with canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, internet-explorer-9, html5-canvas

Are dashed/dotted lines now supported in IE9 Canvas? Currently i'm doing something very similar to the following:

```
var CP = window.CanvasRenderingContext2D && CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype;
if (CP && CP.lineTo){
  CP.dashedLine = function(x,y,x2,y2,dashArray){
    if (!dashArray) dashArray=[10,5];
    if (dashLength==0) dashLength = 0.001; // Hack for Safari
    var dashCount = dashArray.length;
    this.moveTo(x, y);
    var dx = (x2-x), dy = (y2-y);
    var slope = dy/dx;
    var distRemaining = Math.sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy );
    var dashIndex=0, draw=true;
    while (distRemaining>=0.1){
      var dashLength = dashArray[dashIndex++%dashCount];
      if (dashLength > distRemaining) dashLength = distRemaining;
      var xStep = Math.sqrt( dashLength*dashLength / (1 + slope*slope) );
      if (dx<0) xStep = -xStep;
      x += xStep
      y += slope*xStep;
      this[draw ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](x,y);
      distRemaining -= dashLength;
      draw = !draw;
    }
  }
}
```

found from: [override line stroke in canvas for dashed/dotted lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576724/dotted-stroke-in-canvas)

This works great in IE7, IE8, IE9 Compatibility Mode and FireFox, however, in IE9 and Chrome, a solid stroke is drawn for each dotted line.

Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something else is wrong. It works just fine in Chrome:

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.dashedLine(10,10, 100, 100,[4, 4])
ctx.stroke();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MPg5X/1/