# How can the css dottled border be implemented?

Tags: css, gwt, canvas

I want to use GWT Canvas to draw a dashed border around a canvas element like Rectangle.
I like the style that the css attribute `border: dashed` produces, especially the way the corners are displayed, like seen here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-style

Can the "source" code of how this dashed line is produces be inspected somewhere?

Comment: Try downloading the source for Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Downloading_Source_Archives I don't know what language it is, but the answer is probably in there somewhere... :)

Comment: There is no way you can block a client-side code, the best you can do is minify/uglify.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found this function in the Firefox source: `nsCSSRenderingBorders`. I don't understand the code, but the answer probably lies in there.

http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/base/nsCSSRenderingBorders.cpp

Comment: OK thats probably more complicated than I thought. Anyhow it's what I was looking for, I don't see why this answer got a downvote.

Answer (score -1):

If you want that styling for your borders :

```
element.style {
  background-color: palegreen;
  border-style: dashed;
}
```

or

```
element.style {
  border-style: 2px dashed #000;
}
```

Is this what you want ?

If you want a java function to do so, or some place to start to 'study' go here [gwtcanvasdemo.](http://gwtcanvasdemo.appspot.com/) and there is a link to the sources. Also, another post on SO related to the subject [dotted stroke in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576724/dotted-stroke-in-canvas) and then, there is [/DashedLineRenderer.java](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-g2d/source/browse/trunk/gwt-g2d/src/gwt/g2d/client/graphics/DashedLineRenderer.java?spec=svn120&r=120)

Comment: No I'm aware of this. I'm just looking for a java function to draw dashed line around eg a Rectangle (to draw on GWT Canvas as mentioned).