# css line between 2 link ids

Tags: javascript, html, css, line

I'm hoping this will make sense. I want to make a line form between to link ids. This can be done with js if possible or css or a combination of them both. The line will be going in all directions from one point to another on a custom map.

E.g point a connects with point b. If I can control the colour of the line then great. If I can make it dashed.. even better. I have tried using a polyline over the top but it doesn't sit in the same place on all browsers. Hence why i'm hoping that there is a more elegant solution using js?

Any help would be great.

Chris

Comment: in SO the only sense make by code(your effort) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use canvas for this purpose :

http://jsfiddle.net/eAK88/

This will help.

**JS**

```
var ptA = [50,10];
var ptB = [200,250];
var color = '#ff0000';

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(ptA[0],ptA[1]);
ctx.lineTo(ptB[0],ptB[1]);

ctx.strokeStyle = color;
ctx.stroke();
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="300" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
```

For dashed line or dotted line :

**Ref :** [Drawing Dashed lines on HTML5 Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397036/drawing-dashed-lines-on-html5-canvas)