# What is an alternative method for drawing dashed lines on an HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**Question Background:**
I am working on a site that, along with other data, draws vertical and horizontal lines on an HTML canvas.  That page can be converted to a PDF file when the user wants to download the report.  Originally we were using one default style line to draw the graph values.  Recently we added a second type of data on the graph and used `context.setLineDash([x,x])` to draw dashed lines for the second data type.  This works great in browsers.  However, when the PDF converter software tries to convert a report with dashed lines, the dashed lines do not show up in the resulting PDF.

After some troubleshooting, I narrowed the problem down to the `setLineDash()` property.  It appears our converter sofware can understand normal style lines but does not understand the `setLineDash()` property.  The converter software is several years old and I have been informed that an updated version of the converter will not be bought.  I also discovered that there is no support for our version from the creator.

**Question:**  Since I am unable to update our HTML to PDF converter software or get support for it directly, can anyone provide an example of an alternative way to draw a dashed line on a canvas without using `setLineDash()`?

**EDIT**

@K3N,

As per the instructions on the notification I received when you marked this question a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4576724/5152586), I am editing to explain how it is different.

I believe that though the answers to both questions will likely be similar, my question is not a duplicate of the question you indicated.  I concede that both questions are asking for a way to draw dashed lines on a canvas.  However, the other question is asking how to implement a dashed line by *any* method.  My question specifically states that I cannot use the `setLineDash()` property to draw a dashed line.  This difference limits the possible answers and I believe it is enough to make both questions sufficiently distinct.

Comment: So what's wrong with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4577326), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4663129) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7210370) answer to the linked question? Those are three out of the current top four answers, and none of them use `setLineDash()`. It seems to me that your question is essentially a specific case of the more general question it's marked as a duplicate of, and it happens to be a case that is well covered by the existing answers.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen, a fair point.  I was interpreting the word _duplicate_ using its dictionary definition.  I was under the impression that duplicate questions were exact copies of other questions (like if someone were to copy and paste someone else's question text.)  I will try to keep in mind for future questions that it is apparently more of a fluid "duplicate" than an exact match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create line segments.

The function will draw a dashed line from the info in the `dashArr`  eg [2,2] will draw a line 2 pixels then a gap 2 pixels and repeat.

```
function dashedLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,dashArr){
    // get the normalised line vector from start to end
    var nx = x2 - x1;
    var ny = y2 - y1;
    const dist = Math.sqrt(nx * nx + ny * ny);  // get the line length
    nx /= dist;
    ny /= dist;
    var dashIdx = 0;  // the index into the dash array
    var i = 0;        // the current line position in pixels
    ctx.beginPath();  // start a path
    while(i < dist){   // do while less than line length
         // get the line seg dash length
         var dashLen = dashArr[(dashIdx ++) % dashArr.length];
         // draw the dash
         ctx.moveTo(x1 + nx * i, y1 + ny * i);
         i = Math.min(dist,i + dashLen);
         ctx.lineTo(x1 + nx * i, y1 + ny * i);
         // add the spacing
         i += dashArr[(dashIdx ++) % dashArr.length];
         if(i <= 0) { // something is wrong so exit rather than endless loop
              break;
         }
     }
     ctx.stroke();  // stroke
}
```

```js
    function dashedLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,dashArr){

        var nx = x2 - x1;
        var ny = y2 - y1;
        const dist = Math.sqrt(nx * nx + ny * ny);
        nx /= dist;
        ny /= dist;
        var dashIdx = 0;
        var i = 0;
        ctx.beginPath();
        while(i < dist){
             var dashLen = dashArr[(dashIdx ++) % dashArr.length];
             ctx.moveTo(x1 + nx * i, y1 + ny * i);
             i = Math.min(dist,i + dashLen);
             ctx.lineTo(x1 + nx * i, y1 + ny * i);
             i += dashArr[(dashIdx ++) % dashArr.length];
             if(i <= 0) { // something is wrong so exit rather than endless loop
                  break;
             }
         }
         ctx.stroke()
    }
    
    
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
dashedLine(0,0,300,150,[5,5]);
```

```css
canvas { border : 2px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: If OP is only talking about straight `lineTo` this is good, but I fear he should have used the word "path".

Comment: @Kaiido The OP's question is " can anyone provide an example of an alternative way to draw a dashed line on a canvas " and if he wants to draw a path, then repeat the line using distance traveled at the end of one to start the next.

Comment: Yes, that's what he said, and I only said that I hoped it's what he really said because otherwise no, when I use the word *"path"* it's explicitly to include other path methods, and I don't think it's as easy as *"repeat the line using distance traveled at the end of one to start the next"*.  or can you prove me wrong with [this simple path](https://jsfiddle.net/rs4q6yqj/)? That's all I said, and I did upvote because yes, as it currently stands, and if we take the words for what they are, then your answer is *"good"*. But if he used *"line"* because he had *set**Line**Dash* in his brain...

Comment: @Kaiido For a path the answer is it can not be done as you can not access the path data without rewriting all context2D functions that affect or create a path, arc, ellipse, lineTo, moveTo, rect, strokeRect, strokeText, quadraticCurveTo, bezierCurveTo, scale, translate, transform, setTransform, stroke(Path2D), save, restore, did I miss any. It would be easier to modify the failing PDF writer, or forget the dash and use colour. The line answer provides a simple quick solution for paths created from line segments, and looking at the dup answer (65+ for bad buggy code), this is much more robust.

Comment: @kaiido, thanks for pointing out the ambiguity regarding line type in my original question.  I've edited that portion of my question to be more specific regarding the lines.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing a similar problem and I used a different approach to solve this problem. I am posting it in case someone else is having the similar problem.

You can set the stroke pattern on canvas context. Stroke pattern can be any canvas pattern. So here I created an image of 1 pixel height and 6 pixel width. First three pixels were black and other three were white. Now I created the image to create a repeating pattern.

```
var linePattern;
imageToUsedAsPattern.onload = function() {
    linePattern = context.createPattern(imageToUsedAsPattern, "repeat");
    context.strokeStyle=linePattern; 
}
var imageToUsedAsPattern = new Image();
imageToUsedAsPattern.src = "images/linePatterns.jpg";
```

Now all the calls to context.stroke will use the pattern to draw strokes. Like if you create a line from the top left corner of the canvas to the bottom right corner it will be a dashed line.

```
context.moveTo(0,0);
context.lineTo(canvas.width,canvas.height);
context.stroke();
```

See the full explanation at the following link
https://shamailamahmood.blogspot.com/2019/02/html5-canvas-drawing-draw-dotted-or.html